# How to set cell width when export .xlsx files with js-xlsx

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx

I am trying to set a fixed column/cell width to my exported excel files with js-xlsx.

EDIT:

Here is the source of js-xlsx: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

[image: Data View]

Comment: Can you please provide more information with your question ? I don't know where I can't find js-xlsx and they is no code sample here

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I found a snippet the the write test here https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/blob/master/tests/write.js#L14-L19

For quick reference, where ws is your worksheet.

```
var wscols = [
    {wch:6},
    {wch:7},
    {wch:10},
    {wch:20}
];

ws['!cols'] = wscols;
```

Comment: Amazing! @ShermanL that was great! i have a question, how can i merge cells?

Comment: my guess is something like this would work: ws['!merges'] = [ {s: {c: 0, r:0 }, e: {c:0, r:3}} ]}; this would merge <column 0, row 0> (A1) to <column 0, row 3> (A3). (reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-xlsx)

Comment: The Excel takes other values than the ones I specify in the code. For example, if I specify `wpx: 50` in the code, it is 83 pixels in the Excel. Do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 33):

Extending the question, if you need to set automatic width base on your content, you can write as following:

```
const worksheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(arrayOfArray);
worksheet['!cols'] = fitToColumn(arrayOfArray);

function fitToColumn(arrayOfArray) {
    // get maximum character of each column
    return arrayOfArray[0].map((a, i) => ({ wch: Math.max(...arrayOfArray.map(a2 => a2[i] ? a2[i].toString().length : 0)) }));
}
```

This function assumes your first row has most columns. It then tries to find the widest cell in each column by calculating content character length.

Comment: Do you know how I could make it work for array of objects?

Comment: @Žilvinas you'll need to use `for...in` to loop over the object attributes

Comment: @Žilvinas Extended @Icycool answer to array of objects, and preventing the function to crash when cells are empty, since you cant toString when the cell was cleared. Also included columns width to the equation.




`const fitToColumn = data => {

  const columnWidths = [];

  for (const property in data[0]) {

    columnWidths.push({

      wch: Math.max(
        property ? property.toString().length : 0,
        ...data.map(obj =>
          obj[property] ? obj[property].toString().length : 0
        
)

      )

    });
  }

  return columnWidths;
};`

Answer (score 12):

Similar to cell width, you can set the cell height in the following way

```
var wsrows =  [
                 {hpt: 12}, // row 1 sets to the height of 12 in points
                 {hpx: 16}, // row 2 sets to the height of 16 in pixels
               ];

ws['!rows'] = wsrows; // ws - worksheet
```

***Hint:*** If your worksheet data is auto generated and you don't know how many rows and columns are getting populated then you could use the following way to find the number of rows and columns in the worksheet for doing cell width/height formatting.

```
var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(ws['!ref']);
var noRows = range.e.r; // No.of rows
var noCols = range.e.c; // No. of cols
```

Answer (score 10):

Nothing new, but explicitly using the `width` property makes it a bit easier to maintain:

```
ws['!cols'] = [{ width: 20 }, { width: 20 }, { width: 150 } ]; //set col. widths
```

Here is the full list of properties you can give to these `ColInfo` objects though, they give reasons why each width exists, but they state you should use `width` > `wpx` > `wch`, depending on the type of sheet you have and what is available for your use case. More can be read here: https://docs.sheetjs.com/
[image]

Comment: this one also working for table_to_sheet; thanks man!

Answer (score 5):

```
public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {

   const header = Object.keys(json[0]); // columns name

   var wscols = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {  // columns length added
     wscols.push({ wch: header[i].length + 5 })
   }
   const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
   worksheet["!cols"] = wscols;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Automated width by any content:

```
  private fixWidth(worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet) {
    const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json<any>(worksheet)
    const colLengths = Object.keys(data[0]).map((k) => k.toString().length)
    for (const d of data) {
      Object.values(d).forEach((element: any, index) => {
        const length = element.toString().length
        if (colLengths[index] < length) {
          colLengths[index] = length
        }
      })
    }
    worksheet["!cols"] = colLengths.map((l) => {
      return {
        wch: l,
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I used @Icycool 's answer as great example. I also upvoted that one as it was very useful for me.

I enhanced it a bit with a configurable default width if the content is smaller than the title and added a buffer so that it doesn't look crammed together.

Added comments and expanded to increase readability

```
 return Object.keys(dataSource[0][0]).map((key) => {
  return ({
    //pick the data value that has the most content
    wch: Math
      .max(...dataSource[0]

        //Iterate over the column object and return a width for each one
        .map((dataObj: any) => {

          //Return the width as the number of chars with a buffer
          let keyWidth = key.toString().length
          let width = dataObj[key]?.toString().length ?? defaultColumnWidth
          width = width + columnWidthBuffer

          //use a default with if it's smaller than the title
          if (width < keyWidth) {
            width = keyWidth
          }
          return width
        })
      )
  })
});
```